# stateless component compare param every time parent rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a stateless component that was written like this

```
//stateless component
const ComponentOne = ({ month }) => {
    console.log(month); // print incremental of 1 when I render parent component
}
```

and the month is passed from its parent.

```
render(){
    return(
        <ComponentOne month={ month }/>
    )
}
```

It it parent I can change the month and pass it down. How can I check whether the month is different after each time the parent rendered? Use componentWillRecieveProps? But the component has been a stateless component.

Answer (score 0):

A dumb component must be used for the purpose of rendering only and you should handle all the logic in you main component.

You can validate the month within the parent component's function or you can pass another prop to the dumb component which will be the previous value of the month prop and then compare it like

```
const ComponentOne = ({ month, prevMonth }) => {

    if(month != prevMonth) {
          //do what you want here
    }
    console.log(month); // print incremental of 1 when I render parent component
}

render(){
    return(
        <ComponentOne month={ month } prevMonth={this.state.prevMonth}/>
    )
}
```